# Allow access to Webform form URL only through Ajax

Tags: webforms, ajax, 9

I'm using Webform to create some forms, those forms must be showed in modal through Ajax, and all of this is working good.

The issue is that I need URL to the form in order to load the form in modal, but I need to deny access to the form URL and allow it only through Ajax.

So, if user try to get `/forms/my-form` to get 403, and if I get the same URL in Webform Ajax Modal to allow it.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Are there distinct headers in the Ajax requests? If not, this is impossible. Are you already implementing alterations to Webform’s routes, to insert your access controls?

Comment: There is a trait for that /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Ajax/AjaxHelperTrait.php.